# Cannot find symbol error- variable randomNumbers and variable input

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java. Can somebody please help me identify and fix the errors in the following code? Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class p6_35
{

public static void main( String[] args )

    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    toMultiply();

    }

    public static void toMultiply();
    {
        int number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt();
        int number2 = randomNumbers.nextInt();

        System.out.printf( "How much is %d times %d?\n", number1, number2 );
        int answer = input.nextInt();

        int corrAns = number1 * number2;

        if( corrAns == answer )
        {
        System.out.print( "Very good!" );
        }

        while( corrAns == answer )
        {
         number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt();
             number2 = randomNumbers.nextInt();

             System.out.printf( "How much is %d times %d?\n", number1, number2 );
             answer = input.nextInt();

             corrAns = number1 * number2;

             if( corrAns == answer )
             {
            System.out.print( "Very good!" );
             }
        }

       while( corrAns != answer )
       {
            System.out.printf( "No. Please try again.");
            answer = input.nextInt();

            corrAns = number1 * number2;

            if( corrAns == answer )
            {
           System.out.print( "Very good!" );
            }
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `randomNumbers` because it is only local to the `main` method. One thing you can do is move your `randomNumbers` declaration and initialization outside the `main method` and make it static so all methods in your class could access it. This would be known as creating a global variable.

Also, as a Java beginner, you should work on your naming conventions so you could avoid picking up on bad habits. Your class name appears to be very obscure. The name of your method/class/field should reflect what it represents/does.

Comment: Actually 6.35 is the exercise number in the book that I am using to learn Java. But I'll keep your advice in mind. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I make it static?

Comment: Nonetheless, surely this exercise must have a title? :P And it would look something like this: `static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)` and that line would go above your `main` method. After that, you may remove the `Scanner` declaration and initialization in your `main` method.

Comment: Ok,the program works now. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: No problem sir. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined Random instance within main method and trying to access from other method's body. Try to define the random instance outside the main method or pass the instance of random to toMultiply method as parameter